# BigInteger: Way to change base to 2 when writing to file using ofstream in C++?

Tags: c++, biginteger, radix

I'm using the BigInteger Library in C++ to multiply some large numbers and write them to file. However, I want to change the base of the numbers before writing them.

I've tried using `std::setbase()` however it only changes it to base 8, 10 and 16. For example trying `setbase(2)` gives an error.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "BigIntegerLibrary.hh"
#include "BigIntegerUtils.hh"
#include "BigIntegerAlgorithms.hh"
#include "BigUnsigned.hh"
#include "BigUnsignedInABase.hh"
#include "BigInteger.hh"
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
...
        str1=randomStrGen(k);
        str2=randomStrGen(j);

        BigInteger s1 = stringToBigInteger(str1);
        BigInteger s2 = stringToBigInteger(str2);

        myfile<<str1<<" "<<str2<<" "<<"10"<<" "<<setbase(2)<<s1+s2<<" "<<s1*s2<<"\n";
...
```

Gives the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
[Inferior 1 (process 5156) exited with code 03]
```

BigInteger Library downloaded from https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/, 2010.04.30 Release.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488011/printing-the-binary-representation-of-a-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `std::setbase(2)` does **not** switch to a binary representation, see [here on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setbase):

> Values of base other than 8, 10, or 16 reset basefield to zero, which corresponds to decimal output and prefix-dependent input.

Here is an own implementation to get a binary representation of a `BigUnsigned` which will be stored into a `std::string`, note that it assumes that your machine stores values in **little endian** representation.

The function `convertToBinary()` expects a `BigUnsigned` because this type can perform more mathematical operations such as getting bits. This also means that it can only work for **unsigned numbers**.

Further you should consider about using an other library as this library will no longer be maintained (last release from 2010) as stated [here](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/index.html):

> I have lost interest in maintaining this library and will not respond to most development or support inquiries.

**Full code:**

```
#include "BigIntegerLibrary.hh"    
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string convertToBinary(const BigUnsigned& bigUns)
{
   std::string binary;
   for (size_t idx = 0; idx < bigUns.bitLength(); ++idx)
   {
      binary += (bigUns.getBit(bigUns.bitLength() - 1 - idx) ? "1" : "0");
   }

   return binary;
}

int main()
{
   std::string str1 = "12";
   std::string str2 = "18446744073709551615"; /* uint64 max */
   BigInteger s1 = stringToBigInteger(str1);
   BigInteger s2 = stringToBigInteger(str2);
   s2 = s2 * 2;

   std::cout << s1 << ": " << convertToBinary(s1.getMagnitude()) << std::endl;
   std::cout << s2 << ": " << convertToBinary(s2.getMagnitude()) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
12: 1100
36893488147419103230: 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110
```

---

For native types you can get the binary representation as said in the comments and already answered [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488011/printing-the-binary-representation-of-a-number).

---

**Edit #1:**

As the OP talked about a general conversion with any base in the comments below here is a version that will convert a `BigUnsigned` to any base returning a `std::string`, the function name is `convertToAnyBase()`. It is inspired by [this snippet](https://www.phanderson.com/C/baseprnt.html). But this works just with **unsigned numbers** like the solution before.
To check those big number conversion there is a great online tool called [numberfacts](https://www.numberfacts.com/36893488147419103230).

**Full code (contains also the code from above):**

```
#include "BigIntegerLibrary.hh"    
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string convertToBinary(const BigUnsigned& bigUns)
{
   std::string binary;
   for (size_t idx = 0; idx < bigUns.bitLength(); ++idx)
   {
      binary += (bigUns.getBit(bigUns.bitLength() - 1 - idx) ? "1" : "0");
   }

   return binary;
}

std::string convertToAnyBase(const BigUnsigned& bigUns_P, unsigned short base)
{
   static const char baseDigits[16] =
      { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
        '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

   BigUnsigned bigUns = bigUns_P;

   std::string anyBaseString;
   std::vector<size_t> convertedNumber;
   convertedNumber.reserve(bigUns.bitLength());

   /* convert to the indicated base */
   while (bigUns != 0)
   {
      convertedNumber.push_back((bigUns % base).toUnsignedInt());
      bigUns = bigUns / base;
   }

   /* store result in reverse order */
   for (std::vector<size_t>::const_reverse_iterator curNumber = convertedNumber.rbegin();
        curNumber != convertedNumber.rend();
        ++curNumber)
   {
      anyBaseString += baseDigits[*curNumber];
   }

   return anyBaseString;
}

int main()
{
   std::string str1 = "12";
   std::string str2 = "18446744073709551615"; /* uint64 max */
   BigInteger s1 = stringToBigInteger(str1);
   BigInteger s2 = stringToBigInteger(str2);
   s2 = s2 * 2;

   std::cout << s1 << " binary: " << convertToBinary(s1.getMagnitude()) << "\n"
             << s2 << " binary: " << convertToBinary(s2.getMagnitude()) << "\n"
             << std::endl;

   std::cout << s1 << " binary: " << convertToAnyBase(s1.getMagnitude(), 2) << "\n"
             << s2 << " binary: " << convertToAnyBase(s2.getMagnitude(), 2) << "\n"
             << std::endl;

   std::cout << s1 << " octal: "  << convertToAnyBase(s1.getMagnitude(), 8) << "\n"
             << s2 << " binary: " << convertToAnyBase(s2.getMagnitude(), 8) << "\n"
             << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
12 binary: 1100
36893488147419103230 binary: 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110

12 binary (any base function): 1100
36893488147419103230 binary (any base function): 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110

12 octal (any base function): 14
36893488147419103230 octal (any base function): 3777777777777777777776
```

---

**Edit #2:**

An easier approach to convert to any base is to use the capabilities that the BigInteger Library provides. It provides a `BigUnsignedInABase` class which supports the conversion to a `std::string`, but also this just works for **unsigned numbers**:

```
std::string convertToAnyBase(const BigUnsigned& bigUns, unsigned short base)
{
   BigUnsignedInABase bigBase(bigUns, base);
   return static_cast<std::string> (bigBase);
}
```

If you want to work also with signed numbers you have to work with the [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). There is no `operator !` ([Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)) or `operator ~` ([One's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement)) in the BigInteger Library available so you have to do it on the bits and add one for your own.

But this would only work for the binary (base 2) conversion. The other bases are suffering from the fact that the BigInteger Library saves the `BigInteger` as sign + BigUnsigned as aggregated number, so that there isn't any other binary representation of negative numbers here.

Another possibility would be to write the sign (`BigInteger::getSign()`) in front of the string and keep the positive number e.g.:

```
-12base{10} = -1100base{2} = -14base{8}
```

This is an easy code change as you just have to pass `BigInteger` instead of `BigUnsigned` and use the appropiate method.

Comment: Really appreciate you laying out the code for me. Plenty of BigInt libraries around so hopefully I can find another good one.

Just wondering, for what I'm doing I'm looking to implement this code with a base of 2 up to 10, would this be the best way to implement a general code where you can pass a base parameter? I'm fairly new to coding so not sure I understand *everything* going on in your implementation.

It does look elegant though :)

Comment: @Dave: I extended my answer and also provide a general function: `convertToAnyBase()` which can convert from a base between 2 and 16.

Comment: @Dave: Both function will just work for positive numbers!